# Differential equation with two special functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I was wondering if there is a special technics on this problem.
I have two differential equation with respect to time $t$.

$\dot{p}=p(1-p) \lambda $ where $\lambda>0$

$\dot{\pi} = \pi (1-\pi) \alpha$ where $\lambda>\alpha>0$

And finally $p_{0}=\pi_{0}=c$ stating that the initial points are the same.

Once solved the differential equations, I know that $p=\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{c+e^{\lambda t}}$ and $\pi=\frac{e^{\alpha t}}{c+e^{\alpha t}}$

However, my problem is that I have another differential equation like $f(p)= g(p,\pi, \frac{d \pi}{dp})+f’(p)p(1-p))\lambda $

I guess there would be no closed-form solution, but at least I would like to know what kind of problem I am trying to solve.

The equation $f(p)$ per se is not expressed with time variable $t$ but with $p$ and $\pi$. However, both are functions of $t$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi$ can be expressed in terms of $p$:
$$
\pi(p)=\frac{\left(\frac{cp}{1-p}\right)^\tfrac{\alpha}{\lambda}}{c+\left(\frac{cp}{1-p}\right)^\tfrac{\alpha}{\lambda}}
$$
The problem boils down to:
$$
f'(p)=f(p)\frac{1}{\lambda p(1-p)}+\skew3\tilde{G}(p)
$$
This is a linear first order ODE and can be solved explicitly:
$$
f(p)=-\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^\tfrac{1}{\lambda}\int_1^p(1-s)^\tfrac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}s^{-\tfrac{\lambda+1}{\lambda}}\skew3\tilde{G}(s)ds+K\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^\tfrac{1}{\lambda}
$$

Comment: I was wondering if there is a reference about solving the differential equation. Or, could you briefly explain how you solved it?